# How to get v,r,s value for permit() signed token approval for a gnosis-safe as the owner?

Tags: erc-20, javascript, gnosis-safe, meta-transactions, eip712

I have a gnosis-safe and an ERC-20 contract with `permit(owner, spender, value, deadline, v, r, s)` method that requires **v,r,s** of the owner as the argument.

I have calculated the required **v,r,s** value for an **EOA as owner** using its private keys directly and it worked without any problem.

Now I am not able to figure out how to achieve the same for a **gnosis-safe as the owner**.

There is one method named **signTypedData** in gnosis-safe-sdk but it takes SafeTransaction type as input which is not at all similar to the kind of typed-data I am aware of.

**typed-Data that I used while signing via EOA looks something like this,**

```json
{
  "types": {
    "EIP712Domain": [
      {
        "name": "name",
        "type": "string"
      },
      {
        "name": "version",
        "type": "string"
      },
      {
        "name": "chainId",
        "type": "uint256"
      },
      {
        "name": "verifyingContract",
        "type": "address"
      }
    ],
    "Permit": [
      {
        "name": "owner",
        "type": "address"
      },
      {
        "name": "spender",
        "type": "address"
      },
      {
        "name": "value",
        "type": "uint256"
      },
      {
        "name": "nonce",
        "type": "uint256"
      },
      {
        "name": "deadline",
        "type": "uint256"
      }
    ]
  },
  "primaryType": "Permit",
  "domain": {
    "name": "JEBA",
    "version": "1",
    "chainId": "0x61",
    "verifyingContract": "0xf2A622494b8328d2Ed0E6FB1AeEA9B750624a488"
  },
  "message": {
    "owner": "0xC20C81665AF4104Bb6405F9Bdb19a6FF645C6B0a",
    "spender": "0x24Cd34c77DFcb50b5C473b9eEEAa5c57Af730D64",
    "value": "10000000",
    "nonce": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002",
    "deadline": "0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff"
  }
}
```

From an EOA account, this typed-data can be signed using both **ecsign method of ethereumjs-util** and **ethers.SigningKey.signDigest**, which gives me **v**,**r** and **s** value which is then can be used to call **permit** method.

**whereas, the SafeTransaction type is something like this,**

```
export declare enum OperationType {
    Call = 0,
    DelegateCall = 1
}
export interface MetaTransactionData {
    readonly to: string;
    readonly value: string;
    readonly data: string;
    readonly operation?: OperationType;
}
export interface SafeTransactionData extends MetaTransactionData {
    readonly operation: OperationType;
    readonly safeTxGas: number;
    readonly baseGas: number;
    readonly gasPrice: number;
    readonly gasToken: string;
    readonly refundReceiver: string;
    readonly nonce: number;
}
export interface SafeTransaction {
    readonly data: SafeTransactionData;
    readonly signatures: Map<string, SafeSignature>;
    addSignature(signature: SafeSignature): void;
    encodedSignatures(): string;
}
```

I am not able to figure out how to use **typed-data** json in the **SafeTransaction** object, so that I can call **safeSdk.signTypedData(safeTransaction)** with the safe account to get the v,r,s values.

Comment: also posted here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74313248/erc-20-permit-call-with-eip-712-signing-from-a-gnosis-safe-using-gnosis-safe-sdk

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the implementation of the token contract, but the implementation defined by original [permit standard](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-2612) doesn't imply smart contract wallet support.

Many smart contract wallets (incl. Safe) support transaction batching, so you can batch the approval and swap into single transaction. It makes permits redundant.